# -XX:MaxRAMPercentage with respect to K8S request and limit

Tags: java, kubernetes

If I use -XX:MaxRAMPercentage for Java running in a container, and in the K8S definition I provide request and limit values for the container's memory, what will happen?

For example, if the request is 1GB and the limit 2GB, what will be the initial value for the JVM's max memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory limit applies to the cgroup. So assuming you are using a JVM version 10+, where +UseContainerSupport is enabled by default, your JVMs max memory will be the configured percentage of the limit, i.e. if -XX:MaxRAMPercentage has a value of 100 then your max memory will be 2GB.

Memory request is only used for scheduling of new pods. I.e. Kuberentes won't schedule a pod on a node that has less than the requested memory available.

Reference:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run